# How to programmatically retrieve smtp server details from web.config

Tags: c#, web-config

I have the following SMTP details stored in web.config

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="isds@ixtent.com">
        <network host="mail.domain.com" port="25" userName="username" password="password" defaultCredentials="true"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

How can I retrieve these values from within a c# class.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
Configuration configurationFile = WebConfigurationManager
    .OpenWebConfiguration("~/web.config");
MailSettingsSectionGroup mailSettings = configurationFile
    .GetSectionGroup("system.net/mailSettings") as MailSettingsSectionGroup;
if (mailSettings != null)
{
    int port = mailSettings.Smtp.Network.Port;
    string host = mailSettings.Smtp.Network.Host;
    string password = mailSettings.Smtp.Network.Password;
    string username = mailSettings.Smtp.Network.UserName;
}
```

Comment: A small nit: Wouldn't "~/web.config" be more reliable?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to send email with this mail-server-details you don't need to read the settings and apply. These settings are applied implicitly in the application.

If you are reading it for any other reason I was about to write something similar to Darin's answer. But just as I was writing I found he answered so please refer to his answer if you actually need to read. :)

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
string fullpath = @"C:\FullPath\YourFile.config";
string configSection = "system.net/mailSettings";
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(fullpath);
MailSettingsSectionGroup settings = 
    config.GetSectionGroup(configSection) as MailSettingsSectionGroup;
```