# How to programmatically store (save) SMTP server details back to web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config, system.net.mail

Searching StackOverflow, I found [this question on how to Retrieve SMTP settings from Web.Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019175/how-to-programmatically-retrieve-smtp-server-details-from-web-config), but no details on how to update the SMTP back to the web.config file.

I started with the following code:

```
Configuration webConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
MailSettingsSectionGroup settings =
  (MailSettingsSectionGroup)webConfig.GetSectionGroup("system.net/mailSettings");
SmtpSection smtp = settings.Smtp;
SmtpNetworkElement net = smtp.Network;
```

but was quickly clued in by Intellisense that `SmptSection.Network` is a Get (aka "read-only") accessor.

So how am I supposed to programmatically write my SMTP data back to web.config?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this, does this work?:

```
Configuration webConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
MailSettingsSectionGroup settings =
    (MailSettingsSectionGroup)webConfig.GetSectionGroup("system.net/mailSettings");
SmtpSection smtp = settings.Smtp;
SmtpNetworkElement net = smtp.Network;
net.Port = 25;
net.Host = "localhost";
webConfig.Save();
```

Comment: Duh. Thanks. That was it.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article: http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/8461.aspx

Looks like you need fairly high access (permissions) though.

Specifically from the article:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");

    wwDbResourceProviderSection Section = config.GetSection("wwDbResourceProvider") as wwDbResourceProviderSection;

    Section.ShowControlIcons = true;
    config.Save();

    return;
}
```

Comment: I took a look at the article and it looks like a description on how to create custom sections. I was hoping for a more standardized way of writing back to the already established "System.Net" section of the web.config XML file.